# SQL query with PARALLEL hint allocating far more processes than specified

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query of the following form:

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ * FROM …
```

The query is quite complex. When I look at the execution plan, I see PX COORDINATOR four times. Apparently, what happens is that for each PX COORDINATOR this query allocates 8 processes. 
When I start the query, it starts with 8 processes. Then after a while, the sub-jobs of the first PX COORDINATOR are done, and the second starts, again allocating 8 processes without releasing the other 8. During the final stage 32 processes are allocated of which only 8 are used (i.e. active). What’s more, if during the execution Oracle cannot allocate 8 processes at a time (because it hits the max server limit), then it continues working in one single process (which results in very long execution times).

Is there a way to optimize this query in such a way that Oracle releases the unused processes during query execution, or to limit the query to 8 without wasting any CPU time on inactive processes?

**EDIT 2:**
From my limited testing it seems that these PX COORDINATORs depend on the CTEs (subqueries defined in the WITH clause). For such subqueries that have joins, Oracle will process them under sperate PX COORDINATORs. `UNNEST` and `MERGE` hints do not seem to help much.

**EDIT:**

The query:

```
WITH covh AS (
    SELECT    covh.cntr_id
            , covh.covh_valid_from_dt AS vf
            , svar_id
            , svar.variable_name
            , covh.covh_value_alpha AS alpha
            , covh.covh_value_boolean AS bool
            , covh.covh_value_numeric AS num
            , covh.covh_value_pointer_id AS pid
            , covh.covh_value_date AS dt
            , NVL(ora_hash(ora_hash(covh_value_alpha) || ora_hash(covh_value_boolean) || ora_hash(covh_value_numeric) || ora_hash(covh_value_pointer_id) || ora_hash(covh_value_date)), -1) AS hash 
    FROM    SOME_TABLE covh
    INNER JOIN SOME_TABLE_2 svar USING (svar_id)
), covh_lag AS (
    SELECT    covh.*
            , LAG(hash, 1, -2) OVER (PARTITION BY cntr_id, svar_id ORDER BY vf ASC NULLS LAST) lagging_hash
    FROM    covh
), fch AS (   
    SELECT    
              covh_lag.*
            , NVL(LEAD(vf, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY cntr_id, svar_id ORDER BY vf ASC NULLS LAST), TO_DATE('01-JAN-9999', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) AS vt 
    FROM    covh_lag
    WHERE   NOT (
                    hash = lagging_hash
                    OR (hash = -1 AND lagging_hash = -2) 
                ) 
), base AS (
    SELECT    cntr_id
            , vf
            , LEAD(vf, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY cntr_id ORDER BY vf ASC NULLS LAST) AS vt
    FROM    ( SELECT DISTINCT cntr_id, vf FROM fch ) 
), subs AS (
    SELECT  cntr_id, subs_id
    FROM    SOME_TABLE_3
), merge_step1 AS (
    SELECT  
              base.cntr_id
            , subs.subs_id
            , base.vf
            , base.vt
            , week.num AS DEL_AT
            , freq.alpha AS FREQ
            , sure.pid AS SURE_ID
            , frsu.pid AS FRSU_ID
    FROM    base
    LEFT OUTER JOIN subs ON (base.cntr_id = subs.cntr_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fch week ON (week.cntr_id = base.cntr_id AND week.vf <= base.vf AND week.vt > base.vf AND week.variable_name = 'A')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fch freq ON (freq.cntr_id = base.cntr_id AND freq.vf <= base.vf AND freq.vt > base.vf AND freq.variable_name = 'B')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fch sure ON (sure.cntr_id = base.cntr_id AND sure.vf <= base.vf AND sure.vt > base.vf AND sure.variable_name = 'C')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fch frsu ON (frsu.cntr_id = base.cntr_id AND frsu.vf <= base.vf AND frsu.vt > base.vf AND frsu.variable_name = 'D')
), merge_step2 AS (
    SELECT  
              merge_step1.*
            , pred.pid AS PRED_ID
            , taco.pid AS TACO_ID
            , dura.pid AS DURA_ID
            , tarf.pid AS TARF_ID
    FROM    merge_step1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fch pred ON (pred.cntr_id = merge_step1.cntr_id AND pred.vf <= merge_step1.vf AND pred.vt > merge_step1.vf AND pred.variable_name = 'E')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fch taco ON (taco.cntr_id = merge_step1.cntr_id AND taco.vf <= merge_step1.vf AND taco.vt > merge_step1.vf AND taco.variable_name = 'F')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fch dura ON (dura.cntr_id = merge_step1.cntr_id AND dura.vf <= merge_step1.vf AND dura.vt > merge_step1.vf AND dura.variable_name = 'G')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fch tarf ON (tarf.cntr_id = merge_step1.cntr_id AND tarf.vf <= merge_step1.vf AND tarf.vt > merge_step1.vf AND tarf.variable_name = 'H')
), merged AS (
    SELECT   
              merge_step2.*
            , prca.pid AS PRCA_ID
            , sufo.pid AS SUFO_ID
            , rpot.pid AS RPOT_ID
            , dela.alpha AS AREA
    FROM    merge_step2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fch prca ON (prca.cntr_id = merge_step2.cntr_id AND prca.vf <= merge_step2.vf AND prca.vt > merge_step2.vf AND prca.variable_name = 'I')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fch sufo ON (sufo.cntr_id = merge_step2.cntr_id AND sufo.vf <= merge_step2.vf AND sufo.vt > merge_step2.vf AND sufo.variable_name = 'J')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fch rpot ON (rpot.cntr_id = merge_step2.cntr_id AND rpot.vf <= merge_step2.vf AND rpot.vt > merge_step2.vf AND rpot.variable_name = 'K')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN fch dela ON (dela.cntr_id = merge_step2.cntr_id AND dela.vf <= merge_step2.vf AND dela.vt > merge_step2.vf AND dela.variable_name = 'L')
)    
SELECT    /*+ PARALLEL(8) STATEMENT_QUEUING */
          merged.cntr_id
        , merged.subs_id 
        , merged.vf
        , merged.vt          
        , merged.DEL_AT
        , merged.FREQ
        , merged.SURE_ID
        , merged.FRSU_ID
        , merged.PRED_ID
        , merged.TACO_ID
        , merged.DURA_ID
        , merged.TARF_ID
        , merged.PRCA_ID
        , merged.SUFO_ID
        , merged.RPOT_ID
        , merged.AREA
FROM    merged;
```

The exec plan (2x PX COORDINATOR --> 2x8 processes):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                      | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                               |                             |   209M|   208G|       |  5898K  (2)| 00:14:31 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION                     |                             |       |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR                               |                             |       |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                         | :TQ10003                    |   209M|    13G|       |   777K  (2)| 00:01:55 |  Q1,03 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   4 |     LOAD AS SELECT                             | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |       |       |       |            |          |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      WINDOW SORT                               |                             |   209M|    13G|    18G|   777K  (2)| 00:01:55 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|   6 |       PX RECEIVE                               |                             |   209M|    13G|       |   382K  (2)| 00:00:57 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|   7 |        PX SEND HASH                            | :TQ10002                    |   209M|    13G|       |   382K  (2)| 00:00:57 |  Q1,02 | P->P | HASH       |
|*  8 |         VIEW                                   |                             |   209M|    13G|       |   382K  (2)| 00:00:57 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|   9 |          WINDOW SORT                           |                             |   209M|    10G|    15G|   382K  (2)| 00:00:57 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|  10 |           PX RECEIVE                           |                             |   209M|    10G|       | 52342   (4)| 00:00:08 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|  11 |            PX SEND HASH                        | :TQ10001                    |   209M|    10G|       | 52342   (4)| 00:00:08 |  Q1,01 | P->P | HASH       |
|  12 |             VIEW                               |                             |   209M|    10G|       | 52342   (4)| 00:00:08 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  13 |              VIEW                              |                             |   209M|    39G|       | 52342   (4)| 00:00:08 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|* 14 |               HASH JOIN                        |                             |   209M|  8802M|       | 52342   (4)| 00:00:08 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  15 |                PX RECEIVE                      |                             |    24 |   408 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  16 |                 PX SEND BROADCAST              | :TQ10000                    |    24 |   408 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | P->P | BROADCAST  |
|  17 |                  PX BLOCK ITERATOR             |                             |    24 |   408 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|  18 |                   TABLE ACCESS FULL            | SOME_TABLE_2                |    24 |   408 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  19 |                PX BLOCK ITERATOR               |                             |   209M|  5401M|       | 51979   (3)| 00:00:08 |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|  20 |                 TABLE ACCESS FULL              | SOME_TABLE                  |   209M|  5401M|       | 51979   (3)| 00:00:08 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  21 |   PX COORDINATOR                               |                             |       |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|  22 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                         | :TQ20016                    |   209M|   208G|       |  5120K  (2)| 00:12:36 |  Q2,16 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|* 23 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER BUFFERED             |                             |   209M|   208G|  5301M|  5120K  (2)| 00:12:36 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  24 |      PX RECEIVE                                |                             |   209M|    39G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  25 |       PX SEND HASH                             | :TQ20002                    |   209M|    39G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,02 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 26 |        VIEW                                    |                             |   209M|    39G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|  27 |         PX BLOCK ITERATOR                      |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,02 | PCWC |            |
|  28 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,02 | PCWP |            |
|* 29 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                     |                             |   209M|   169G|  1825M|  4536K  (2)| 00:11:10 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  30 |       PX RECEIVE                               |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  31 |        PX SEND HASH                            | :TQ20003                    |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,03 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 32 |         VIEW                                   |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,03 | PCWP |            |
|  33 |          PX BLOCK ITERATOR                     |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,03 | PCWC |            |
|  34 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 35 |       HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                    |                             |   209M|   157G|  1825M|  4028K  (2)| 00:09:55 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  36 |        PX RECEIVE                              |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  37 |         PX SEND HASH                           | :TQ20004                    |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,04 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 38 |          VIEW                                  |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,04 | PCWP |            |
|  39 |           PX BLOCK ITERATOR                    |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,04 | PCWC |            |
|  40 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,04 | PCWP |            |
|* 41 |        HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                   |                             |   209M|   145G|  1825M|  3544K  (2)| 00:08:44 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  42 |         PX RECEIVE                             |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  43 |          PX SEND HASH                          | :TQ20005                    |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,05 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 44 |           VIEW                                 |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,05 | PCWP |            |
|  45 |            PX BLOCK ITERATOR                   |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,05 | PCWC |            |
|  46 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,05 | PCWP |            |
|* 47 |         HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                  |                             |   209M|   133G|  1825M|  3084K  (3)| 00:07:36 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  48 |          PX RECEIVE                            |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  49 |           PX SEND HASH                         | :TQ20006                    |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,06 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 50 |            VIEW                                |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,06 | PCWP |            |
|  51 |             PX BLOCK ITERATOR                  |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,06 | PCWC |            |
|  52 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,06 | PCWP |            |
|* 53 |          HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                 |                             |   209M|   121G|  1825M|  2647K  (3)| 00:06:31 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  54 |           PX RECEIVE                           |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  55 |            PX SEND HASH                        | :TQ20007                    |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,07 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 56 |             VIEW                               |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,07 | PCWP |            |
|  57 |              PX BLOCK ITERATOR                 |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,07 | PCWC |            |
|  58 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL                | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,07 | PCWP |            |
|* 59 |           HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                |                             |   209M|   109G|  1825M|  2233K  (3)| 00:05:30 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  60 |            PX RECEIVE                          |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  61 |             PX SEND HASH                       | :TQ20008                    |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,08 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 62 |              VIEW                              |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,08 | PCWP |            |
|  63 |               PX BLOCK ITERATOR                |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,08 | PCWC |            |
|  64 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL               | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,08 | PCWP |            |
|* 65 |            HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER               |                             |   209M|    97G|  1825M|  1844K  (3)| 00:04:33 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  66 |             PX RECEIVE                         |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  67 |              PX SEND HASH                      | :TQ20009                    |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,09 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 68 |               VIEW                             |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,09 | PCWP |            |
|  69 |                PX BLOCK ITERATOR               |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,09 | PCWC |            |
|  70 |                 TABLE ACCESS FULL              | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,09 | PCWP |            |
|* 71 |             HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER              |                             |   209M|    85G|  1825M|  1478K  (3)| 00:03:39 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  72 |              PX RECEIVE                        |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  73 |               PX SEND HASH                     | :TQ20010                    |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,10 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 74 |                VIEW                            |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,10 | PCWP |            |
|  75 |                 PX BLOCK ITERATOR              |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,10 | PCWC |            |
|  76 |                  TABLE ACCESS FULL             | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,10 | PCWP |            |
|* 77 |              HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER             |                             |   209M|    73G|  1825M|  1135K  (3)| 00:02:48 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  78 |               PX RECEIVE                       |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  79 |                PX SEND HASH                    | :TQ20011                    |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,11 | P->P | HASH       |
|* 80 |                 VIEW                           |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,11 | PCWP |            |
|  81 |                  PX BLOCK ITERATOR             |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,11 | PCWC |            |
|  82 |                   TABLE ACCESS FULL            | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,11 | PCWP |            |
|* 83 |               HASH JOIN OUTER                  |                             |   209M|    61G|  3201M|   816K  (3)| 00:02:01 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|* 84 |                HASH JOIN OUTER                 |                             |   209M|    22G|  1676M|   520K  (3)| 00:01:17 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|* 85 |                 HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER          |                             |   209M|    10G|       |   302K  (3)| 00:00:45 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  86 |                  PX RECEIVE                    |                             |    23M|   538M|       | 16751   (4)| 00:00:03 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  87 |                   PX SEND HASH                 | :TQ20012                    |    23M|   538M|       | 16751   (4)| 00:00:03 |  Q2,12 | P->P | HASH       |
|  88 |                    PX BLOCK ITERATOR           |                             |    23M|   538M|       | 16751   (4)| 00:00:03 |  Q2,12 | PCWC |            |
|  89 |                     TABLE ACCESS FULL          | SOME_TABLE                  |    23M|   538M|       | 16751   (4)| 00:00:03 |  Q2,12 | PCWP |            |
|  90 |                  PX RECEIVE                    |                             |   209M|  6201M|       |   285K  (3)| 00:00:43 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
|  91 |                   PX SEND HASH                 | :TQ20013                    |   209M|  6201M|       |   285K  (3)| 00:00:43 |  Q2,13 | P->P | HASH       |
|  92 |                    VIEW                        |                             |   209M|  6201M|       |   285K  (3)| 00:00:43 |  Q2,13 | PCWP |            |
|  93 |                     WINDOW SORT                |                             |   209M|  4401M|       |   285K  (3)| 00:00:43 |  Q2,13 | PCWP |            |
|  94 |                      PX RECEIVE                |                             |   209M|  4401M|       |   285K  (3)| 00:00:43 |  Q2,13 | PCWP |            |
|  95 |                       PX SEND HASH             | :TQ20001                    |   209M|  4401M|       |   285K  (3)| 00:00:43 |  Q2,01 | P->P | HASH       |
|  96 |                        VIEW                    |                             |   209M|  4401M|       |   285K  (3)| 00:00:43 |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  97 |                         SORT GROUP BY          |                             |   209M|  2800M|  4820M|   285K  (3)| 00:00:43 |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  98 |                          PX RECEIVE            |                             |   209M|  2800M|       |   285K  (3)| 00:00:43 |  Q2,01 | PCWP |            |
|  99 |                           PX SEND HASH         | :TQ20000                    |   209M|  2800M|       |   285K  (3)| 00:00:43 |  Q2,00 | P->P | HASH       |
| 100 |                            SORT GROUP BY       |                             |   209M|  2800M|  4820M|   285K  (3)| 00:00:43 |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
| 101 |                             VIEW               |                             |   209M|  2800M|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
| 102 |                              PX BLOCK ITERATOR |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,00 | PCWC |            |
| 103 |                               TABLE ACCESS FULL| SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,00 | PCWP |            |
| 104 |                 PX RECEIVE                     |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
| 105 |                  PX SEND HASH                  | :TQ20014                    |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,14 | P->P | HASH       |
|*106 |                   VIEW                         |                             |   209M|    11G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,14 | PCWP |            |
| 107 |                    PX BLOCK ITERATOR           |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,14 | PCWC |            |
| 108 |                     TABLE ACCESS FULL          | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,14 | PCWP |            |
| 109 |                PX RECEIVE                      |                             |   209M|    39G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,16 | PCWP |            |
| 110 |                 PX SEND HASH                   | :TQ20015                    |   209M|    39G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,15 | P->P | HASH       |
|*111 |                  VIEW                          |                             |   209M|    39G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,15 | PCWP |            |
| 112 |                   PX BLOCK ITERATOR            |                             |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,15 | PCWC |            |
| 113 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL           | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D75E2_25751CCB |   209M|    14G|       |   159K  (1)| 00:00:24 |  Q2,15 | PCWP |            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I materialize each of the `merge_steps` with the `/*+ MATERIALIZE */` hint (to save temp space used), then I get one PX COORDINATOR for each materialized step. I can not add the query here: the question body is limited to 30k characters.

Comment: It might help to know what your query is...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Added the query & exec plan.

Comment: Ouch.  First, stop ...using... `USING` - you're going to end up joining three tables with identical column names when you only wanted to join two of them, so get out of the habit now.  I'm guessing you're seeing this behavior because of the nesting in your query.  I can't immediately tell for sure (and don't have the time right now), but you can probably use fewer levels; sample starting data and desired results would help spot this (although there's no reason why `merge`/`merge_step1`/`merge_step2`  have to be separate - doesn't Oracle support `PIVOT`?).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I only used `USING` once to join 2 tables. And there is indeed no reason for splitting the query into steps. With the above query, Oracle will make hash tables for each join all at once, consuming over 50GB temp space for 200M records. But when using the `/*+ MATERIALIZE */` hint on each of these steps the temp space is greatly reduced (to some 20GB per step – at the cost of increased execution time and 2 more PX COORDINATORs). And yes, `PIVOT` might possibly improve performance… but that’s more about rewriting the query and not necessarily solving my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

I think Oracle starts 8 parallel processes for each of the main 4 queries --> 32 processes in total. Oracle cannot reuse the first 8 processes to query a different sql while the result of the first 8 processes will be used later on.

Improve performance:

a) I would try to rewrite the query. The queries merge_step1, merge_step2 and merged look like they can be handled in one query. My time is limited, I'm afraid, otherwise I would give it a try myself.

b) Do you have the option to create a materialized view which stores the result of the query? If so, this can improve the performance significantly. I would consider this option even if a) was successful.

Comment: That is the whole point. What does make a query "main"? And how can I force Oracle to consider the whole query as main, or atleast to force the less demanding "main" queries to execute in one process. Defining queryblocks with `QB_NAME` and forcing them to execute in one process doesn't seem to do the trick when some other QB is forced to execute with 8 processes. a) why I use the merge_steps is explained in one of the comments. And rewriting the query is a possibility, but what guarantee do I have it will use less 'main' queries after I rewrite it? b) It is a MV allready, but not efficient.

Comment: Well, I looked a bit deeper into your SQL statement and painted a picture how sqls are connected.
Optimizing such a SQL statement can take 1 or 2 working days so you will need some time... but I guess you know that already :)

I would suggest you combine the three statements "covh", "covh_lag" and fch into one sql statements. Afterwards you combine "base", "subs" and "merge_step1" into one statement.

By this we get a better overview on the sql plan and sql statement. In addition we give Oracle's optimizer the chance to optimize the execution. Right now there is not much it can do.